# Line break issue when displaying file contents in html text area - javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, textarea, line-breaks

I am trying to display the contents of a text file into a text area element but the am having issues with a line break being displayed as '\n' instead of actually doing it.

```
<textarea id = "textArea" name = "textArea" data-ng-model="note.text"></textarea>
```

javascript to add the text to text area element

```
var $promise=$http.post("http://localhost/PHP/findNotes.php", data); //send data to user.php
$promise.then(function(msg){

       document.getElementById("textArea").value = msg.data;

      });
```

PHP file to get file contents

```
$note=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));  //get note 
$noteId = ($note->noteId);  
$userId = ($note->userId); 

$filename = 'file://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/Notes/'.$userId.'/'.$noteId.'.txt';

if (file_exists($filename))   
{  
  $file = fopen($filename, "r");  
  while (!feof($file))   
  {  
    $display = fgets($file, filesize($filename));  
    echo $display; 
  }  
  fclose($file);  
}   
else   
{  
  echo "Error occurred!";  
}
```

When reading the file with content

```
line1\nline2\n\nline4
```

the exact same thing is shown in the text area

However if the file contents is applied directly to the textarea in the js code then the linebreaks work perfectly.

so if the JS is changed to

```
document.getElementById("textArea").value ="line1\nline2\n\nline4";
```

then the output in the text area is correctly:

```
line1
line2

line4
```

Would appreciate any help, it seems as if it's a problem with the format of the text received from PHP? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the \n character for ajax to \\n

So before you echo $display in findNotes.php you should insert:

```
$display=str_replace("\n", "\\n", $display);
```

Comment: I think the correct version is $display=str_replace("\\n", "\n", $display); but thanks that works. If you edit your answer I will accept it

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved. But if you want to escape \n with a second backslash, my code is correct. From the manual: `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Comment: Oh right for some reason the text remained the same, unless I changed around the \\n and \n